# Troubleshooting Glassfish jdbc realm

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish

Below is the error I'm getting when trying to login with a user, but it tells me pretty much nothing, where do I go in glassfish to get some more information? Is my hash not the same as GFs? Does it not like my database design? How do I know?

```
SEVERE: jdbcrealm.invaliduserreason
WARNING: WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Change javax.enterprise.system.core.security logging level to FINEST.
2. Commence digging.